# How to fix a `xeus-cling` kernel runtime error on Mac OS (C++ Jupyter kernel stdlib errors)

Tags: c++, macos, kernel, jupyter, xeus-cling

I installed `xeus-cling` with the usual `conda install xeus-cling` and get the following runtime errors when I go to start a C++ kernel (11, 14 and 17 versions) in the Jupyter notebook:

```
/opt/anaconda3/envs/cling/include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:143:12: error: no member named 'ldiv' in the global namespace
  return ::ldiv(__x, __y);

< many such errors, eventually >

/opt/anaconda3/envs/cling/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:122:9: error: no member named 'rand' in the global namespace
using ::rand;
      ~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

I tried re-installing XCode command line tools - no go. Same setup works fine on my Linux machine.

How can I fix these errors and get the kernel to start?

I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-cling/issues/412) with the recent XCode version 12.5.1 (12E507) - it looks like either `xeus-cling` conda package is using an incompatible toolchain, or XCode is misconfigured - either way, the C++ kernel won't start. Conda 4.10.1 with Python 3.9.6 (in case this matters). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you by any chance install things from both conda-forge and default ? Try to make the channels strict ? Which macos os version ? and M1 or intel mac ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Installed Xcode. Install both conda-forge and default. I am running Big Sur on my Mac mini M1 chip and MacBook Pro on intel. Both had the same issues. What do you mean by making the channels strict

Comment: +1 to the above response: same problems on Intel and M1, both conda channels (also tried others), same Big Sur 11.3.1

Comment: I have the same issue on my MacBook Pro on intel with Big Sur 11.5.

Comment: Same error on macbook pro on M1 with macOS Monterey

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-cling/issues/403) (GitHub)

SylvainCorlay suggests trying:

```
conda remove libcxx --force
```

And it worked for me (MacOS Monterey, Mambaforge)